# Can't get group's unseenCount

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

we use the following HTTP GET request to get group's info:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$select=visibility,unseencount

Until today (18 Sep 2018) it worked, but today it stopped working. Now Postman returns 403 Forbidden: ErrorAccessDenied (message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again).

When unseencount is removed from url data is returned successfully with the same bearer token:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$select=visibility

Also in our app which uses Sharepoint SPFx and HttpClient it currently returns 400 Bad request for the same url.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing that. Have you tried this out in the Graph Explorer signed in as your user (eliminates some mistakes possibly you not seeing in Postman etc.)? http://aka.ms/ge

Is it consistent for all groups? What about ones that the user belongs to?

You will need Group.Read.All to access this property. Ensure that's coming back in your access token.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_get

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for your response. We don't use personal accounts for getting the groups info. Instead we use Azure AD app (registered in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) which has the following permissions:

Application permissions:
- Directory.ReadWrite.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All

I've tried to add explicitly Group.Read.All but it didn't help.

For clarity I've also tried that in Graph explorer with my personal admin account. There after I granted Group.Read.All permissions to explorer app - unseencount was successfully returned. But this is not our case as we use app permissions

Comment: can I ask you to submit an Azure Support Ticket for this, as this is an issue, not really a Q&A. quick video to show how to do this https://twitter.com/jthake/status/1030489336439959553

Comment: yep we submitted support ticket and got some valuable feedback. First of all about 403 error in Postman: it was actually side effect because we used app only permissions there while unseencount may be currently retrieved only with delegated permissions. There is known issue for that: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs//concepts/known_issues#groups-and-microsoft-teams

"Examples of group features that support only delegated permissions:
...
    User favorites and unseen count"

Comment: actual error which we got in the app 400 bad request was caused by different thing (in the app we make calls to Graph API from javascript with user context i.e. use delegated permissions): when try to get group info and select unseencount and custom group schema extension property (which stores additional group metadata) like this

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$select=unseencount,customPropertySchema

we get 400 bad request error:
"Multiple properties with the name 'id' were detected in a resource or a complex value. In OData, duplicate property names are not allowed"

Comment: It happens because now when you try to retrieve only unseencount:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$select=unseencount

or only custom property

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/group/{groupId}?$select=customPropertySchema 

Graph API returns also group id in addition to requested unseencount/custom property. And when it tries to merge results it throws this "Multiple properties with the name 'id' were detected in a resource or a complex value" error.

Comment: But when you try to select e.g. visibility

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/group/{groupId}?$select=visibility

it returns only visibility without group id.

And this is something new because it worked until yesterday. I.e. Graph API started to return group id when you request unseencound or custom group property. According to the our contact person from support ticket it was possible to reproduce this issue on MS side and this problem will be now escalated to product team. Waiting for feedback.

Comment: If you have escalated this to a support ticket and the product team is engaged there. That is the best place for it. Did you get this resolved? What was the ticket number?

Comment: We don't have ticket number. There were several people working on this but we still didn't get clear answer.

Comment: Had response from MS last week that issue had been fixed. We tested it and it is really fixed now